# Vue js cant drag input type file

Tags: vue.js

If I upload an image then drag it. It seems that **input[type='file']** was static. Because the other value will be drag to other row only the **input[type='file']** was remained. How can I move/drag it together with other value?

This is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/darkrulerbreaker/c24nncm5/7/)

This is the HTML

```
<div id="main">
  <h1>Vue Draggable Image</h2>
    <div class="drag">
      <h2>List 1 Draggable</h2>
      <draggable v-model="list" class="dragArea" :options="{group:{ name:'people',  pull:'clone', put:false }}">
        <form v-for="(element, index) in list" :key="index" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <input type="text" v-model="element.name">
          <input type="file" id="reference_image" @change="onFileChange($event,index)" name="reference_image" accept="image/*" />
          <img class="small_image" :src="reference_image" name="reference_image" />
        </form>
      </draggable>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the script

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: "#main",
  data: {
    list: [{
        reference_image: "",
        name: "name 1"
      },
      {
        reference_image: "",
        name: "name 2"
      },
      {
        reference_image: "",
        name: "name 3"
      },
      {
        reference_image: "",
        name: "name 4"
      },
      {
        reference_image: "",
        name: "name 5"
      },
    ],
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

get it working by changing `:key="index"` to  `:key="element.name"` 
fiddles :

https://jsfiddle.net/amherve/sqebLtzc/3/